# How billing is working on Azure for Hosting a Website (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, azure, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I just moved to .Net programming and built a website based on ASP.NET MVC 5 framework.
I come from php programming and I have to admit that MVC has some good advantages.

However , when it comes to deploy website on the internet I'm a bit lost.
I decided to go on Azure, while it seems to much problem to deploy the Microsoft framework on a linux servers ( and it s does not seem optimized)

However I don 't understand at all the pricing policy with this cloud system.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/

What is a Compute instance  ? 
And what is this hour rate ? 
Does it mean that no one access to your website during one hour this won't be charged ? 
The memory they mentioned is it RAM memory ? 
If yes it's seems to be very few compared to a normal server.

I'm looking for something enough fast. 
Moreover I developed my website with a PostgreSQL, but I have the impression that I have to order a separate virtual machine which will host my database.

I'm sorry if my questions are a bit vague, but it's so much different than a simple Apache server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compute instance on Azure, is something that has a CPU reserved for you. This can mean, it is not used at all and just waiting for your command.

Examples of compute engines are:

- Virtual Machine
- Web site

You can run a free Website on Azure. You cannot use your own domain (at least not supported by Azure), and they will stop when not used. This means the first request is slow, the second and later requests are good. When you get too many requests, it will not fit anymore in a free site, but a startup will fit.

If you are outsite the free range, Azure bills per hour (or even minute), that you have the site (or virtual machine) active.

The RAM seems small, but if you have no UI running, you need a lot less RAM.

The advantage of Azure is you can run on a small cheap machine, but you can upgrade very fast, even for a few hours.

Comment: it does not bother me to pay especially if I have to to use my own domain name. I'm just looking for something which is fast for my users and be able to run cron.  As I have some fucnciton which calls external API I hope that the bandwith on cloud service is not too slow... I guess I will it a try anyway while it seems to complicated to run the latest version of MVC5 with depencies on mono.

Comment: The network you can trust, if you want to run Cron you can choose for a Website combined with scheduled tasks, or a virtual machine.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer.. I will need a virtual machine anyway for my postgre sql database I guess